# In the X-UA-Compatible tag, what do the "X" and "UA" actually stand for?

Tags: internet-explorer, http-headers, meta-tags, microsoft-edge, web-standards

I'm curious about the meaning of the letters, and haven't been able to find an answer. What are they abbreviations for? I already understand how the tag is used. (There's an excellent summary of usage and history [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6771258/whats-the-difference-if-meta-http-equiv-x-ua-compatible-content-ie-edge-e)).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "X" is a prefix conventionally used by vendors to denote non-standard HTTP headers. It has since been [deprecated](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6648).

"UA" stands for user agent. For most users, the user agent is the web browser, so it makes sense in context.

I'm surprised none of the documentation for X-UA-Compatible actually says what "UA" stands for. Perhaps the documentation simply assumes the author already knows. It doesn't help that web searches for "UA" turn up entirely different expansions for the same abbreviation altogether.

Comment: Thank you very much! This was exactly the answer I was looking for.

Comment: The document mode story is a hard one to tell.  Details important to some complicated the story for others.  As with many projects, it boiled down to a question of resources, triage, feedback, and schedule.  The initial drafts of the documentation included such a discussion (along with links to other user agent articles, e.g. the string); however, these drafts were deemed too long in review and were subsequently cut to focus on the minimum content deemed necessary.  A separate task to better document custom header support was cut due to resource limitations.